# jquery specify task are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="index.js">
</script>
```

This is named as index.html with jquery ui and my js script

The following is the **index.js** code in which the effect explode is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#breg').click(function(){
    $('#breg').effect('explode');
});
```

});
And the following code with the fadeIn **slow property** is also not working

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#breg').click(function(){
    $('#breg').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: You've loaded jQuery twice !

Comment: What is inside your body tag in index.html

Comment: Where is #breg, please post the relevant HTML for that too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're going for here but here is something that works using the UI features you mention above:

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNRvro)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        #breg {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        #breg2 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#breg').click(function(){
                $(this).effect('explode');
            });
            $('#breg2').click(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut('slow');
            });
            $('button').click(function () {
                $('#breg').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#breg2').fadeIn('slow');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="breg"></div>
<div id="breg2"></div>
<button>Reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```